# How to specify a directory for "spark.sparkContext.textFile()"?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, directory, windows-10

I have downloaded the following code `rating.py` to see if my `Spark` working correctly.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

lines = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/ml-100k/u.data")
ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2])
result = ratings.countByValue()

sortedResults = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
for key, value in sortedResults.items():
    print("%s %i" % (key, value))
```

Both `rating.py`file and `ml-100k` folder are inside `C:\\SpikeCourse` directory, and the code uses the following line to loading them up:

```
lines = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/ml-100k/u.data")
```

But I can't understand how `C:\\SpikeCourse` changed to `file:///SparkCourse/ml-100k/u.data`? Or for example, if my files are within `E:\\` instead of `C:\\` directory, how should I specify that?

PS: I am using Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

In windows you have to escape "\"

Try:

```
lines = sc.textFile("C:\\SparkCourse\\ml-100k\\u.data")
```